# Java Socket creation takes more time

Tags: java, sockets

I have given `Socket soc = new Socket(host,port);` Now when the host machine is up and in running state, the socket is getting created immediately.

But when the machine is turned off or rebooted then this line takes around 40 seconds to respond. I tried using `soc.setSoTimeout(timeout);` But this line is used after creation of Socket. Hence it doesn't help much.

Also this seems to be a bug in JAVA itself.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;:YfiG?bug_id=5092063

I have tried few workarounds given in this link like adding the machine port and host name in the etc/hosts file. But it doesn't work. Because of this delay due to DNS resolution while socket creation, the response time of my system gets severely affected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Sr

Comment: What happens if you specify INADDR_ANY (ie, 0) for the host ip?  Do you have an actual need to restrict it to a particular interface?  Or is it the client side that's experiencing the slowness?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [connect with timeout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29) method

```
// create an unconnected socket
Socket soc = new Socket();
soc.setSoTimeout(SO_TIMEOUT); // if you like

// connect (with timeout)
soc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
```

Comment: To clarify, setSoTimeout() sets a *read* timeout. The connect() method with 3 parameters lets you control the *connect* timeout: at least, it lets you reduce it from the default.

Comment: @EJP: Good clarification! (better than my comment :) )